# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Connect(App)) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Connect(App))
> /> outside a

The above error occure when I wrap my App component with withRouter. This error while occure when I made following changes,

```
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter (connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in separate lines

```js
const ReduxApp = connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(App)
export default withRouter(ReduxApp)
```

You won't need `withRouter` if you pass the props in the `Routes`

```
 <Route path="/" component={(p) => <Component {...p} {...props}/>} />
```

Here `p` is the props related to react router and `props` is the redux state

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(App)));
```